# htmlcleaner only scrape first body tag and child nodes

Tags: java, htmlcleaner

I'm using java htmlcleaner and I'm looking to scrape only the first body tag and all it's children. I'd like to omit html, head, doctype tags.

I seen nodeByXpath, but it appears to only work in ant and not java. Does anybody know how to do this in java?

Answer (score 0):

When run with `nodeByXPath` command line arg, HtmlCleaner evaluates the entire document and then calls `evaluateXPath(...)` on it.
So there won't be any performance gain and you can do it manually.